# Port forwarding private ip while using different ip for qbittorrent

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, vpn, openvpn

My server setup:

```
Server OS: Ubuntu 18.04
application: qBittorrent-nox
VPN Provider: PIA
Private IP: 172.16.0.5
VPN IP(eg.):96.91.86.163
Reverse Proxy: Nginx
```

Is it possible to make qBittorrent-nox use the VPN while I use a reverse proxy or port forward my private IP?

I found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface

Will qBittorrent be accessible outside my network in a revere proxy if I setup to the private IP `172.16.0.5:8080` eve though qBittorrent is setup with a different IP?

How can I test that qBittorent is setup to a separate IP?